# Unity VS code is not working like the tutorial

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, compiler-errors, youtube

complete beginner here. I was watching a [tutoral](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QkbGr1rAya8&list=PLrnPJCHvNZuCVTz6lvhR81nnaf1a-b67U&index=4&ab_channel=CodinginFlow)  on YouTube and was following the code. However mine contains errors such as "The name 'input' does not exist in the current context" and missing directives. My code is the exact same as in the video.
I've looked around on the internet but I haven't found a good solution yet. I have all the needed extentions and preferences.

```
void Update()
    {
       if (Imput.GetKey("space"))
       {
            GetComponent<Ridgidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector3(0, 14, 0);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code has typos and different casing than the error you indicated. Check for typos on your side, and if the problem still exists, update your question with the _full_ actual problem code.

Answer (score 0):

There are some spelling errors. Try this:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey("space"))
    {
        GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector3(0, 14, 0);
    }
}
```